# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: wcf

i simply created a wcf service which is printing `"hello world"`. created a sequential console workflow, added a send activity and code activity to the workflow. referenced the service here. configured the send activity. created dependency property for return value.

now when I am running the app. it throws a format exception in `program.cs` file on the line

```
WorkflowInstance instance = workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(Using_SendActivity.Workflow1));
```

Where have I gone wrong?

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message="Input string was not in a correct format."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Int32.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetStringTable(Boolean isHelp)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_NameTable()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String machine, String category)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName, String machineName)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName)
       at System.Workflow.Runtime.PerformanceCounterManager.SetInstanceName(String instanceName)
       at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.StartRuntime()
       at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.InternalCreateWorkflow(CreationContext context, Guid instanceId)
       at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(Type workflowType)
       at Using_SendActivity.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\as73043\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Using SendActivity\Using SendActivity\Program.cs:line 28
  InnerException:
```

wcf file i am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfServiceForSendActivity
{
    // NOTE: If you change the class name "Service1" here, you must also update the reference to "Service1" in App.config.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        #region IMyService Members

        public string GetResponse()
        {
            return string.Format("Hello World !!!");
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: What you have done wrong is that you have failed to post the complete exception, including the stack trace and all inner exceptions. Do that, and you'll have a chance of having your question answered. You may even need to post some code.

Answer (score 1):

On Win7 run 'lodctr /R' from an elevated command prompt and restart to reload perf counters.

This KB has more details for older OS's.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956

Answer (score 1):

See [PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists throwing 'Input string was not in a correct format.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152428/performancecountercategory-exists-throwing-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-for) for a similar exception.

The solution is to perform the registry cleanup explained at:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;300956