# PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists throwing 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Tags: c#, perfmon

When I'm checking for the existance of a performace category using

```
PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("myCategory")
```

on a system (clean install of XP SP3) where the category doesn't exist I'm getting the following exception thrown ...

```
    Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
       at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
       at System.Int32.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetStringTable(Boolean isHelp)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_NameTable()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String machine, String category)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName, String machineName)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName)
```

Not wanting to blame the framework :) what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** After checking the Performance Object list - it's full of numbers rather than the normal text - looks like the list is corrupt - going to try [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;300956)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Turned out to be a very corrupt registry. To fix I got (from the KB in the question) perfc009.dat and perfh009.bat from the xp disc (see [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888017) for expanding off the disc)
and popped them into %systemroot%/system32.

Comment: This manafested itself when using PolyMon on a Windows 2003 server, doing the same (from an W2K3 Disc) worked in my case, without apparant side effects. Thanks.

Comment: You can also run `Lodctr.exe /r` from the command prompt (source: http://exchangepedia.com/2008/06/perfmon-counters-show-up-as-numbers.html)